# Making a 2-Dimensional Object Array

Tags: c++

So i want to place an object into a 2 Dimensional Array. I did this. I wanted 26 Rows and 30 Columns. Whenever I would append. For example `array[0][0] =` to some object of class `Object`. It would set `array[0][1]`, `array[0][2]`, `array[0][3]`, and so on to the same details of `array[0][0]`. I want the object to go exactly where I put it and not on the rest of its row. Am I allocating the memory wrong?

```
class Object{
     string Name
}

main()...
Object** array= new Object*[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
{
    array[i] = new Object[30];
}
```

Comment: why array is of both Profile and Object type...

Comment: Changed sorry i wanted to generalize words, forgot to change that one.

Comment: your allocation should be fine but you won't be able to do things like `array[1][2]`.  Why don't you just do a `Object array[26][30];` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that looks right. Only thing to point out is that this is an array of pointers (or dynamic array.) Remember to clean up the memory afterwards. Also, with more than 26x30, the performance is not good. Try to be creative.

Comment: When i print out the memory of    <code> array[0][1] and array[0][2] </code>  they're exactly the same, and so forth generate the same data. Why is that? I've done this with stings and works out fine.

Comment: You're using dynamic array here. You're printing out the address of the pointer. Try this "array[0][1]->name" and see what happens.